# Task 'details' is not in your gulpfile

Tags: gulp, sitecore, helix

Trying to install gulp. But when check using gulp details command, then getting error like **Task 'details' is not in your gulpfile**. Is anybody face similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is looking for task "details" in your gulpfile.js. You can run `gulp --tasks` to see what tasks are available, but you are for sure not going to see "details".

Here's how to create and define [gulp task](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/creating-tasks/)

So basically, you at least need something similar to the following snippet within your gulpfile.js

```
function details(callback) {
  callback();
}

exports.details = details;
```

Or, if using **require-dir** for better folder structure, you would need the previous code snippet within the referenced file :

```
require('require-dir')('./gulp/tasks/details');
```

And when using npm to run your task, like `npm run details`

You can find those scripts definition in your ***package.json*** file at your project root. There is a node scripts where you can define **npm script**, where you could be calling the ***gulp details task***

```
...
    "scripts": {
                 "details": "gulp details",
              },
...
```

You could run `npm run details`, and it would behind the scene run the gulp task.